# iptables: forward packet to another network

Tags: networking, iptables, openvpn, forwarding

I have two machines on 2 different networks which are interconnected.

#### First network:

- **10.0.0.0/24**

#### Second network:

- **10.0.1.0/24**

The first network is running an OpenVPN under **10.0.0.10** with `ipv4_forwarding` enabled.

The second network is running a bastion server under **10.0.1.20** with `ipv4_forwarding` enabled.

The second network has a routing rule to access some S2S with this range: **10.1.0.0/16**

---

I'm trying to figure out how can I receive packets on the OpenVPN client that will be forwarded to the bastion server and from there to the S2S only when the packets are actually heading towards this specific range (**10.1.0.0/16**).

Do I need to alter the `iptables` on the bastion server or forwarding is sufficient?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Lets talk about the route statement 10.1.0.0/16 for a moment. Is it supposed to accommodate first and second network?

Comment: @BruceMalaudzi Nope, 10.0.0.0/16 will cover both the first and second one, I'm talking about a route on the second network which is accessible from the first network despite there's no direct routing between them (only through the second network).

Comment: Share the output of "ip route show"  from the bastion server

Comment: @BruceMalaudzi all the routing is handled externally so OpenVPN has a connection to the outside world with a route to the local subnet and a peering connection to the bastion server, the bastion server is quite the same in this aspect.